# What happens when a lower energy photon strikes a higher energy atom?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation, photoelectric-effect

I understand that when a higher energy photon hits an atom it could elevate an electron and add energy to the atom, but what happens if a lower energy photon strikes a higher energy atom? If it doesn't elevate an electron, what does that incoming energy do?
Is it still absorbed some how? Or is it scattered elsewhere?

Answer (score -2):

It's simply reflected back. This is why we have spectral lines of different elements. If a photon cannot make an electron 'jump up' another orbital shell, it's just reflected. 
It depends on the electron configuration of the atom and the frequency of the photon. If the photon doesn't have any more energy to add to electron or if it has too little to elevate an electron to the next orbital hell it's just reflected.

Comment: No, that's not right.   The photon can be scattered in any direction, including straight ahead.

Comment: Is this just a standard reflection/scattering interaction, or is there some other interaction taking place first before photon moves on?